# How come this import surprisingly been added?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle, python-import

In class, I was asked to work with IDLE for doing homework. I took the liberty of working with JetBrains PyCharm since I thought it would be more comfortable for debugging and working with many files (without opening multiple windows).

Apparently, without me noticing, two imports has been added to one of my files:

```
from base64 import _bytes_from_decode_data
from operator import is_, truediv
```

I have no idea what caused it.. Maybe someone can share some light? I figured that it something to do with the conversion of strings, only that it wasn't on my mind at all.

Second, before submitting the files, I double checked and saw it runs from IDLE as well. 
It seems I have some libraries on my computer that are not installed on the computer of the one who checks my homework. How come? I can't remember installing something else besides python 3.3.2 files.

Thanks

Comment: I  think your system is infected with zombies who add such stuff to your files

Comment: Haha... Actually I found out what was the problem. It's an annoying feature called Auto Import.
I can't remember doing it but I guess I wrote "byte" and thus few functions were suggested by the Auto complete, mistakenly I pressed Enter, so the auto complete added a call to the function "_bytes_from_decode_data". I erased it, but I had no idea that an import was added as well by the Auto Import.